# ASP.NET MVC: How to put a create partial view in an index view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an index view grid that i would like to put a create partial view at the bottom of-- that way a user can create a new item on the same page as viewing all items. However, upon submitting the partial create view, nothing happens to the main index page; it doesn't update with the new item (although its there after a refresh).

Index page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                PhoneNumberTypeID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PhoneNumberTypeID}) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PhoneNumberTypeID })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.PhoneNumberTypeID %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Name %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>
    </table>

    <p>
        Create New
    </p>
    <% Html.RenderAction("Create"); %>

</asp:Content>
```

And here is the controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Paris.Domain.Access;

namespace Paris.Web.Areas.Domain.Controllers
{
    public class PhoneNumberTypesController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Domain/PhoneNumberTypes/
        private IRepository<Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType> db;
        public PhoneNumberTypesController(IRepository<Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType> context)
        {
            db=context;
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Get().Select(i=>i));
        }
        public ViewResult IndexCreate(Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType num)
        {
            Create(num);
            return View();
        }
        public ViewResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Edit(Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType num)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Update(num);
                    return Index();
                }
                else
                    return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Delete(int PhoneNumberTypeID)
        {
            db.Delete(db.Get().First(i => i.PhoneNumberTypeID == PhoneNumberTypeID));

            return Index();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Create(Paris.Domain.Models.PhoneNumberType num)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Create(num);
                    return View();
                }
                else
                    return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

If i am doing this completely wrong, feel free to point out how my thinking is flawed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `Create` action methods, you are returning just the Create view, not the whole page.  This is because the default behaviour of `View()` is to return a view with the same name as the action method.  Therefore, if you want the Post to return the whole page you need to either specify the correct view name, or even better return a redirect to the Index action. eg: `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 0):

Logically what you are doing is right. However on the submit button of partial create, your entire page should get refreshed. Why is it not happening? Are you using Ajax to create new record?

I guess this is what you are doing:

1. Posting to create action.
2. Record is created and then new record set is fetched from data source.
3. You pass it back to your view (`return View("Index", recordset)`).
4. Index view is refreshed with new record set.

If you are doing these steps then it should work.

Comment: Saw the code. After creating the records, your are just returning "Create" view (return View()). Instead of this you should return to your "Index" view in a way I have suggested in #3 or the way Clicktricity has suggested. Main point here is that you need to trigger reload of your Index view. Once that happens, you will get your desired functionality.